# Loan applicant is not creating

Tags: visual-workflow

We are experiencing some problem with the setting "Automatically generate a loan applicant record for a new residential loan application that’s associated with a person account. Under "Mortgage Settings,". Even though this is turned on, no automatically created Loan Applicant records are created for us. Other than turning on this setting, are there any specific requirements for this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue that you are facing is a ongoing Known Issue Bug(W-12684145) and currently we do not have any ETA about this fix. However fix would be rolled out in coming releases.

Link -> [Please check here](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000sluJFAAY/loan-applicant-does-not-create-automatically-when-an-after-save-flow-is-on-the-residential-loan-application-object) and report your issue .

Thank you.